# Run Safari from terminal with given URL address without open command

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, safari

I'm having trouble with opening Safari from terminal. Command I tried is

```
/Applications/Safari/Contents/MacOS/Safari http://www.example.com
```

Safari opens and tries to navigate to the url:

```
file:///Current/Terminal/Path/Here/http:/www.example.com
```

I know, I could do it using `open`:

```
open -a safari http://www.example.com
```

But I can't. The bigger picture is quite complicated: I'm actually trying to run the browser from command-line .NET application (which is running using mono). I use `System.Process` .NET class to run the command and I have to be able to control the process (get process Id, check if it's active, kill it if necessary, etc.). Using `open` command does not return correct process Id (I tried using `open` with `-W` switch - does not help either).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would doing this in 2 times

- Open safari
- Using AppleScript to open the url `tell application "Safari" to open location "http://www.google.com"`

Here is a oneliner :

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari & sleep 1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to open location "http://www.google.com"'
```

NB: you need to wait before running the AppleScript because Safari is not started yet. The `sleep 1`might not work in every case since it will really depend on how much time Safari will need to start.

Comment: It get's a little more tricky because I'm trying to fire it from `Process` .NET class, but I was able to work problems around using your solution, and that's why I'm setting it as accepted. Thanks!